# How to display non-printable symbols in QTextEdit pyqt4?

Tags: pyqt4, qtextedit

Is there an example of how to display special characters (i.e. u'\u2022', u'\u21b5', u'\u2192') instead of non-printable symbols (i.e. ' ','\n', '\t') in QtGui.QTextEdit PyQt4, but without replacing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tabs And Spaces in QTextEdit example (by use .setFlags and QTextOption.ShowTabsAndSpaces):

```
def initEdit(self):
    doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    option = QtGui.QTextOption()
    option.setFlags(QtGui.QTextOption.ShowTabsAndSpaces)
    doc.setDefaultTextOption(option)
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
    self.textEdit.setDocument(doc)
```